# Convert NSMutableArray to String problem

Tags: nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have got a little problem.

I would like to save an array to a textfile with this code:

```
for(int aa = 0; aa <= [lines2 count]; aa++) {
    content = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@;%@", content, [lines2 objectAtIndex:aa]];
}

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"cart" ofType:@"txt"]; //meine Zeile
[content writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
```

But it crashes my app. Can anybody give me an easy example, how to convert an `NSMutable Array` from

```
One
Two
Three
```

to an `NSString` like

```
One;Two;Three
```

Hope somebody can help me... :(

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the concatenation using somewhat simpler code as below:

```
NSMutableString* content = [NSMutableString string];
for (int aa=0; aa < [lines2 count]; aa++){
    [content appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[lines2 objectAtIndex:aa]]];
}
```

or, You could use componentsJoinedByString.

Comment: I would recommend the componentsJoinedByString approach for clarity and Obj-C idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe less, instead of less_or_equal?

```
for(int aa = 0; aa < [lines2 count]; aa++)
```